# Why does the majority of the microphone current have to flow through R1 in this amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, microphone

In this circuit:

[image]

Why does the part underlined in red matter? I don't understand, why do I want more current flowing through R1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current through R1 is also the biasing current for the JFET inside the microphone capsule. This current sets up an operating point, and the larger this current compared to the loading current (in this case going through C1, R2 and R3) the more stable the operating point becomes, the microphone output is less susceptible to noise (improves signal to noise ratio or SNR), and there is less signal voltage drop as R1 via C1 through R2 and R3 combination makes a voltage divider which drops the microphone's output signal voltage. 
Of course, there is a practical limit to how low this resistance can go, and the microphone manufacturer usually specifies the range of values for this resistor. 
Normally, this resistor has a higher value when you want to reduce microphone's current consumption and noise immunity is not much of a concern (especially if the microphone is fairly close to the next stage or the input of an amplifier connected to it). 
Longer wires and noisier environments will require a lower resistance value which will also present a high load for the induced noise in the wire/cable, improving the SNR. 
Another factor in determining this resistor value is the impedance of the cable or the amplifier which it is connecting to.

Comment: SNR is _higher_ for larger bias resistors since signal voltage grows proportional to the resistance (the FET is essentially operating as variable current source) while noise voltage grows proportional to the square root of the resistance.  However, the resistor must be low enough to admit the drain current while still leaving the nominal operating voltage of the microphone.

Comment: Yes, that's if we look at the microphone alone, thanks for mentioning it, but I was talking about noise on the line in case of large resistances: higher impedance on both ends will also allow higher noise voltage levels to be induced. Generally, induced noise currents are fairly small and easily overloaded by low impedances on ends of line(s), so creating larger signal currents will "overshadow" the noise.

Answer (score 2):

For AC current from the microphone, all of \$R_1\Vert R_2\Vert R_3\$ are a load on the microphone signal, but only the voltage across \$R_1\$ produces a signal on the op-amp. \$R_1\$ is necessary for providing the FET drain current of the microphone capsule.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the part underlined in red matter? I don't understand, why do I want more current flowing through R1?

Increased ac current through R1 provides more ac voltage to the op-amp input. Decreasing R1 to obtain that current is counter productive. It is better to increase \$R_{eq}=R_2//R_3\$ thus reducing the loading effect on the FET drain.

The transfer function from the FET drain current to the op-amp input$$\frac{V_{i}}{I_{FET}}=R_{1}\frac{R_{eq}C_{1}s}{1+\left(R_{1}+R_{eq}\right)C_{1}s}$$ clearly shows the effect R1 has on the drain voltage. Bias circuitry is a high-pass filter.

By setting \$R_{eq}>>R_1\$ the right-hand fraction becomes unity at passband frequencies. Then C1 is chosen for the desired corner frequency.

**Having more current in R1 is a consequence of the tuning of the transfer function rather than a desired target.**

It is more desirable to have a larger R1 for I to V gain and noise performance within the limitations provided in the specifications for the microphone.